# Linux /proc/PID dir of child stays alive after parent kills child

Tags: c, linux, fork, pid, procfs

It seems that if I create a process, fork it and send a SIGHUP from the parent to the child, the child dies but it's "/proc/PID" dir doesn't dissappear until the parent also dies.
(See code below).

What is the right way to let the parent check if the child is dead ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>

void testprocdir(pid_t pid) {
    struct stat sb;
    char path[1024];

    sprintf(path,"/proc/%d",pid);
    if(stat(path, &sb)==-1 && errno == ENOENT) {
            printf("%s does not exist\n", path);
    } else {
            printf("%s exists\n", path);
    }
}

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    pid_t parent,child;

    parent=getpid();
    printf("I am %d\n",parent);
    child=fork();
    switch(child) {
    case -1:
            printf("Forking failed\n");
            return 2;
    case 0: 
            parent=getppid();
            child=getpid();
            printf("I am the child (%d) and my parent is %d\n", child, parent);
            while(1) { sleep(1); printf("I am the child and I have slept 1s\n");}
            printf("This line should not be visible\n");
    }
    sleep(1); //make sure kid is in the while loop
    printf("I am the parent (%d) and my kid is %d\n", parent, child);
    kill(child,SIGHUP);
    testprocdir(parent);
    printf("Waiting 5s before testing if the procdir of the child (/proc/%d) is removed\n",child);
    sleep(5);
    testprocdir(child);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [wait](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) family of system-calls.

Comment: It's worth noting that despite their name, the wait functions do not necessarily "wait".  Using the WNOHANG flag, waitpid() can be made non-blocking, fulfilling the OP's original request to check if the child died.

Answer (score 1):

`fork` returns the PID of the child process in the parent process, and 0 in the child process.

`man waitpid` should provide more than enough direction beyond that to call `waitpid` in the parent, allowing you to check that child process or all child processes ― including the ability to allow the parent to continue executing if the child is still alive or stop all execution in the parent until the child is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I will start with some concepts:

The OS will keep a child process' entry in the process table (including exit status) around until the parent calls waitpid (or another wait-family function) or until the parent exits (at which point the status is collected by the init process). This is what a "zombie" process is: a process that has exited by is still resident in the process table for exactly this purpose. The process' entry in the table should go away after the first call to waitpid.

Also, from the man page :

A child that terminates, but has not been waited for becomes a "zombie". The kernel maintains a minimal set of information about the zombie process (PID, termination status, resource usage information) in order to allow the parent to later perform a wait to obtain information about the child.

So, by using the wait family of functions you can examine the status of child process.
There are some macros also that can be used with with wait family of functions to examine the status of child process like WEXITSTATUS, WIFSIGNALED, WIFEXITED etc .